Connection failed rtsp stream
Using the command-line vlc: & "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" cat_vibing.mp4 --sout "#rtp{mux=ts,sdp=rtsp://:8554/}" and gui client connecting with network url rtsp://@:8554/ works as expected, but the following code don't and I don't know why.
        Core.Initialize();

        var libvlc = new LibVLC("--input-repeat=65545");
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(libvlc);
        var rtsp = new Media(libvlc, _catUri);
        //rtsp.AddOption("{dst=display{noaudio},");
        // gui stream cmd: :sout=#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/} :no-sout-all :sout-keep
        // terminal: & "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" cat_vibing.mp4 --sout "#rtp{mux=ts,sdp=rtsp://:8554/}"
        rtsp.AddOption("#rtp{mux=ts,sdp=rtsp://:8554/}");
        player.Play(rtsp);

Am I missing something ?

Sooo, I thought :sout was supposed to be skipped :/ modified version works
media.AddOption(":sout=#:rtp{mux=ts,sdp=rtsp://10.101.10.124:8554/}");

